# How to sync already existing data in realm db

Tags: xamarin.ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a situation in which I have an offline db with  large data stored .

I want this data be synced with my server realm .

In this case I would have to copy the data from offline db and I would need to paste em into new db  with "SyncConfiguration" config ?

or by any means I can sync the realm db which was created with "RealmConfiguration" . This way I can avoid data migration .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to sync a Realm that was originally created as standalone. You'll need to copy the data manually.

Comment: Already came to term up with that ,wanted to ask does sync happen when app is in background as well ?

Comment: Depends on your app - e.g. on Android, apps are not suspended in the background, so code can continue to execute and sync can happen. On iOS, they are, but also there are variety of background modes that your app can implement so it may remain active in the background.